# multiple request with forkjoin not work angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i want do a multiple request for iterate a many select options with data, im using angular 6, but i give 500 status code, but if i try copy and past url in browser, it work, and in postman work too.
if i do separete request in angular work too, but join request not work

my service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { MEAT_API } from './../app.api';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GrupoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

public carregarDadosParaCadastroGrupo(){
  let grupoTributario = this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/grupotributario`).map((res: Response) => res['value'])
  let unidadeProduto = this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/unidadeproduto`).map((res: Response) => res['value'])
  let secao = this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/secao`).map((res: Response) => res['value'])
  let categoria = this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/categoria`).map((res: Response) => res['value'])
  let subcategoria = this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/subcategoria`).map((res: Response) => res['value'])
  let marca = this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/marca`).map((res: Response) => res['value'])
  return Observable.forkJoin([grupoTributario,unidadeProduto,secao,categoria,subcategoria,marca])
}
```

my component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.grupoService.carregarDadosParaCadastroGrupo().subscribe(responseList =>{
      console.log(responseList)
      this.dadosDaApiParaCadastro = {grupoTributario: responseList[0], unidadeProduto: responseList[1]
        , secao: responseList[2], categoria: responseList[3], subcategoria: responseList[4], marca: responseList[5]}
    })
```

the errors:

[image]

Comment: The issue is not with `forkJoin` have you observed the error you get in console. you need to configure your server to enable [CORS](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#requesting-services-from-a-different-server-cors)

Comment: [I want to add CORS support to my server](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Comment: i dont have acess to backend, and the single request work fine, but when i do multiple request i give this error, if i do all this request one to one with 1 milisecond or more of delay. i dont give this error
obs: i know backend are make with delphi using xdata